# One more greedy sed question

Tags: regex, sed, greedy

I'm doing an automated download of a number of images using an html frame source. So fra, so good, Sed, wget. Example of the frame source:

```
<td width="25%" align="center" valign="top"><a href="images/display.htm?concept_Core.jpg"><img border="1" src="t_core.gif" width="120" height="90"><font size="1" face="Verdana"><br>Hyperspace Core<br>(Rob Cunningham)</font></a></td>
```

So I do this:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*htm?\(.*jpg\).*$/\1/p' concept.htm
```

to get the part which looks like this:

```
concept_Core.jpg
```

to do then this:

wget --base=/some/url/concept_Core.jpg

But there is one nasty line. That line, obvioulsy, is a bug in the site, or whatever it can be, but it is wrong, I can't change it, however. ;)

```
<td width="25%" bla bla face="Verdana"><a href="images/display.htm?concept_frigate16.jpg" target="_top"><img bla bla href="images/concept_frigate16.jpg" target="_top"><br>Frigate 16<br>
```

That is, two of these "**concept_Frigate16.jpg**" in a line. And my script gives me

```
concept_frigate16.jpg" target="_top"><img border="1" src="t_assaultfrigate.gif" width="120" height="90" alt="The '16' in the name may be a Sierra typo."></a><a href="images/concept_frigate16.jpg
```

You understand why. Sed is greedy and this obviously shows up in this case.

*Now the question is, how do I get rid of this corner case? That is, make it non-greedy and make it stop on the FIRST **.jpg?****emphasized text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider changing:

```
\(.*jpg\)
```

into:

```
\([^"]*jpg\)
```

This should stop your initial search going beyond the end of the first `href`. Whether that will introduce other problems (for other edge cases) is a little difficult to say given I don't know the full set of inputs.

If it does, you may want to opt for using a real parser rather than regexes. Regexes are a powerful tool but they're not necessarily suited for *everything.*

Comment: Well, actually, the first href is not a problem, it is guarded by a ^.*html? and I can catch the beginning of the image name in the tag pretty easily. But the second jpg is a real pain. As far as I understand, this [^"] actually works for the jpg", right?

Answer (score 2):

use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^.*htm?\(.*?jpg\).*$/\1/'
```

Comment: Perl would be nice, I thought about it, too, as it is non-greedy, or has non-greedy expressions, at least. I really miss the ? from Perl in sed and other regexp tools.

Comment: @Semen, So why don’t you just use Perl then?

Comment: @tchrist, well, I wanted to solve the problem with sed as I had never used it before and second, listing and automatically downloading images from this very site is an old-standing problem for me. Just wanted to learn wget, then realized I needed some regexp html parsing and remembered about sed. Completely forgotten about perl at the same time. But now I am going to use it, as a non-greedy match turned out to be really necessary upon further refinement of the regular expression and sed can't provide that.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason the above regexp prints out the whole text, not the image names. Any perl option omitted here? Theoretically it must work, as it is effectively identical to the sed regexp I provided.

Comment: This woks: perl -ne 'print unless !s/^.*?htm\?(.*?jpg).*$/$1/' concept.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use [^"] instead of . in the regular expression.
This will pick all characters except the appostrophes.

Comment: Yes, thanks,this worked! So essentially we are using the feature of html tags to put an '"' and to stop on that '"' to work around sed greediness.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n -e 's/^.*htm?\([^"]*jpg\).*$/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep can do PCRE:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\.htm\?).*?jpg' concept.htm
```

Comment: Depends on which version of PCRE it’s linked with!! Make sure you have at least PCRE 8.10.

Comment: `/lib/libpcre.so.3` is version 7.8 on my system.

Comment: you really want to upgrade. Make sure it’s built with PCRE_CONFIG_UTF8 and PCRE_CONFIG_UNICODE_PROPERTIES both enabled.

Comment: @tchrist: `pcretest -C` tells me that those options are enabled. I'm looking at the [changelog](http://pcre.org/changelog.txt) to see what might compel me to upgrade.